# How to get associative array from numeric array in asp

Tags: asp-classic, associative-array

In php it is easy to get an associative array from numerical array, but how do I get an associative array from numerical array in Classic ASP?

Comment: Not sure. Can you show us some code snippets? I.e what is the code you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid vbscript arrays are only like php numeric array and multidimensional arrays.

Alternatively, you might want to try Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") for your needs.